# Redirecting to the https page but not for Java user agents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I would like to redirect all users to the https version of my website **but not ones that use Java for their User Agent** as I have app which does not support SSL yet. I have tried this code but it didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Java.*
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I want RewriteRule to happen in case that user does not use https and the user agent is not Java. I am not the best with htaccess files and I am asking for help with the condition regarding user agent. Java user agents have this format:

*Java/1.7.0_60*

where Java version is behind the slash so I would like to detect if user agent starts with Java.

Comment: sorry this might not be a help, but I would not build in a special behaviour for java agents. As client side code can manipulate the client header someone could use. Any good reason for excluding Java?

Comment: My app requests some pages via http and therefore it is redirected to the https so I get 301 moved permentaly message instead the actual content. If the Java user agent wouldn't get redirected to https, it would get the actual content. The second option would be to update the app to use SSL but this would cost users to update the app and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Does the java app has some kind of cache? Since you use a 301 redirect, it might be using an old, wrong redirect attempt and bypasses the server completely.

Comment: What's not working? Did you check User agent string you are getting on web server?

Comment: I have checked the user agent using netcat and it looks the way as I wrote in the question. And it doesn't use any cache because in case I remove the redirect, everything works with the next launch of the app.